# Regex for hostname

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code (currHost is hostname):

```
if (currHost.match(/(alpha|beta|test|dev|load|local)\./))
```

but I need to add additional conditions such as

- file:

  - .od*. (* is wildcard)
  - dev-wa.
  - .sq*. (* is wildcard)
  - .hbox.

Example MATCHING URLS:

- file://c:blahblahblah
- www.sqc.mydomain.com
- www.sqa.mydomain.com
- www.odd.mydomain.com
- www.odp.mydomain.com
- www.hbox.mydomain.com
- dev-wa.mydomain.com

Example  NOT MATCHING URLS:

- www.sqcmydomain.com
- www.sqamydomain.com
- www.oddmydomain.com
- www.odp.mydomain.com
- www.hboxx.mydomain.com
- dev-waa.mydomain.com

not sure how to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you show us some valid string that should match? Also frame out the rules as bullet points. That would be easier to understand the question.

Comment: Host names can't contain : in them. Are you matching against the whole URL or just the hostname?

Comment: making matches against host but I guess I have to use document.location.href instead of hostname since local files ("files:") won't be included in document.location.hostname

Comment: You are aware that the `file://` is in both the match and not-match list?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, should be only in the match list.

Answer (score 1):

For your file matches you can simply use

```
document.location.protocol == 'file:'
```

and the expression you're looking for is

```
curHost.match(/(alpha|beta|test|dev|load|local|\.od.*|dev-wa|\.sq.*|\.hbox)\./)
```

Just remember that this expression will also match www.od.mydomain.com **and** oddmydomain.com since it's a valid match too. If you don't want this, you need to either specify a full expression (with the .com part) or specify the number of characters after the od/sq part. For example

```
curHost.match(/(alpha|beta|test|dev|load|local|\.od.{1}|dev-wa|\.sq.{1}|\.hbox)\./)
```

For one letter match.

If you want to specifically match those string only in the beginning of the domain, with or without www. you can use

```
curHost.match(/^(www\.)?(alpha|beta|test|dev|load|local|od.+|dev-wa|sq.+|hbox)\./)
```

Comment: Just came back to answer, but this does the trick. You could add `^` in front of the first group to make sure it has to start with those. A bit more secure

Comment: @Tsanyo Tsanev - curHost.match(/(alpha|beta|test|dev|load|local|\.od.{1}|dev-wa|\.sq.{1}|\.hbox)\./) seems to work fine! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Martijn I did, on the 3rd example, but there also were some examples with www. in front, so I didn't want the expression to be too strict.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (currHost.match(/(alpha|beta|test|dev|load|local|file:|dev-wa|od\*|hbox)?\./))
```

Just add like above? Or do you mean something else?. I've added the a slash in from of the asterix. Added a questionmark at the end to make it ungreedy

Comment: `dev*` and `od*` would match hosts like `de`, `devvv`, `od` and `oddd`. That's not what OP needs I think.

Comment: The question mark is outside the expression, that' not valid JS.

Comment: changed it back to the inside and escaped the asterix to what I thing the OP might mean

Comment: @Martijn -the regex doesn't work. The first 6 should be caught by the regex and the second 6 should not match:

    - www.sqc.mydomain.com
 - www.sqa.mydomain.com
 - www.odd.mydomain.com
 - www.odp.mydomain.com
 - www.hbox.mydomain.com
 - dev-wa.mydomain.com
 - www.sqcmydomain.com
 - www.sqamydomain.com
 - www.oddmydomain.com
 - www.odpmydomain.com
 - www.hboxx.mydomain.com
 - dev-waa.mydomain.com

Comment: I'll see if I've got some time to fix it, shouldn't be that hard